# How can I plot a "slice" of the mesh for a 3D plot?

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

I'm using NDSolveValue to solve the Laplacian equation for this geometry:

[image]

I want to view the mesh that NDSolveValue is using, so I do the following:

```
Print@Show[
   Graphics3D[{Opacity[0], lrectregion, Opacity[0], rrectregion}, 
    ImageSize -> Large], sol["ElementMesh"]["Wireframe"]];
```

(where `sol` is the interpolated function that NDSolveValue returns. Its actual form doesn't matter for this question and the code used to produce it is hefty, so I didn't include it.)

However, it's hard to see what's actually going on in the 3D plot that gets generated:

[image]

If I manually zoom in on the boundaries (those rectangles), I can kind of see detail, but still not that well:

[image]

I know about these "slice" functions like [SliceDensityPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceDensityPlot3D.html) that are very helpful for seeing a 2D "slice" of a 3D function in 3D space. **Is there anything like that for visualizing the mesh?**

I've looked at [this article for element mesh visualization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshVisualization.html) but didn't see anything helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no `SliceDensityPlot3D` for mesh visualization. There is no density to plot. The mesh wireframe is a Graphics/Graphics3D object so you can use

```
sol["ElementMesh"]["Wireframe"[PlotRange -> {All, {40, 60}, All}]]
```

[image]

```
Show[
   Graphics3D[{Opacity[0], lrectregion, Opacity[0], rrectregion}, 
    ImageSize -> Large], sol["ElementMesh"]["Wireframe"[PlotRange -> {All, {40, 60}, All}]]
,Boxed->False
]
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. Just to be clear, I didn't think there was a density, I just meant the functionality of looking at a 2D slice of a 3D function.